# Do finite verb and 'main verb' refer to the same thing?

Tags: grammar, verbs

[Your Dictionary Grammar](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/verbs/what-is-the-main-verb-in-a-sentence.html) states that 'main verbs' are also known as finite verbs. However, I can easily find a few instances where a main verb isn't the finite verb of the sentence.

Example: We are learning math

'Learning' is the main verb but 'are' functions as a finite verb.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is the website unreliable?

Comment: There are even worse cases when a finite verb is not the main verb. "I'll give him the last payment when he's finished the job." "When he's finished the job" is a subclause, but it has a finite verb in it.

Comment: I would say the term *main verb* is not very well defined. People use it in different ways. So perhaps the term is best avoided unless you know how the speaker defines it.

Comment: No, they don't. A _finite_ verb is a verb that's inflected for tense; _is_ and _went_ are finite verbs. Non-finite verbs (infinitives and participles) are not inflected for tense. _Main_ verbs are the last verb in a verb chain, following all modals and auxiliaries for Perfect, Progressive, and Passive. They're what the clause is about; the auxiliaries are just window dressing. Every clause has a main verb, though that is sometimes only a tensed auxiliary _be_ with predicat e adjectives and nouns; then the predicates are what the clause is about. But there's a verb.

Comment: @Lee Zhiyuan Forget the term 'main verb'. The catenative-auxiliary analysis is the most sensible way to analyse auxiliaries. The term 'main verb' is misleading, indeed unnecessary. In your example, "are" is analysed as an auxiliary verb, and "learning" as a lexical verb. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> *We are learning math*.

Whether "writing" is called a main verb or not depends on the kind of analysis adopted. There are two kinds: the **dependent-auxiliary analysis** where the core auxiliary verbs are dependents of the following lexical verb, and the **catenative-auxiliary analysis**, where the core auxiliaries are verbs taking non-finite complements.

Under the dependent-auxiliary analysis, your example is a simple clause. Core auxiliaries are contrasted with **main verbs**, so that "are learning" is a syntactic unit in which "learning" is called the main (i.e. head) verb head and the core auxiliary "are" is a dependent. The core auxiliaries are thus never heads in the dependent-auxiliary analysis.

By contrast, under the catenative-auxiliary analysis, "learning math" is a non-finite complement of "are". The tree structure therefore has "learning" as a lexical verb and "are" as an auxiliary. On this view, there is no contrast between auxiliary verbs and main  verbs. "Are" is just as much a main verb as "learning": both are heads of their respective clauses.

Modern grammar tends to favour the catenative-auxiliary analysis.